# How can I use youtube api to upload videos longer than 15 minutes

Tags: youtube-api

I will upload video to Youtube by using Browser-based uploading and Direct uploading Youtube api.

How can I am allowed to upload videos longer than 15 minutes? Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your account will automatically be provisioned for uploads longer than 15 minutes (both through the website and through the API) if you verify the account with a mobile phone. Here's the link:

https://www.youtube.com/verify

Comment: Thanks your help! I have apply it~